# How to write a QString on several lines?

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

Do you have a better way to do that ?

```
QString str("I am a long long long"
              + QString("long long long")
              + QString("long QString") );
```

I don't like all this QString.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In C++ string literals are automatically concatenated when placed next to each other.

```
QString str("I am a long long long"
    "long long long"
    "long QString");
```

Answer (score -1):

the QT way :

```
#include <QString>

QString myStr = QStringLiteral("");
```

Start typing, when you press return, he will auto add the " and open a new line
starting with ".